# flask-wtf multiple validations in same html template

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms

My first webapp and attempt at flask, jinja2, wtforms, etc. I have looked for an answer but i am coming up short. I am trying to render a template with two separate forms that each have unique validation requirements. The problem i am running into is that even if i submit just one form the other form will return validation errors to the user. I want to be able to use both forms independently and not have validation errors on one while the other works. Both forms work currently but not when they share the same template.

Flask:

```
# Main Customer Page
@app.route('/customers/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def customers():
    error = None
    customer_form = AddCustomerForm(request.form)
    address_form = AddAddressForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if customer_form.validate_on_submit():
            add_customer = Customer(
                customer_form.name.data,
                customer_form.email.data,
                customer_form.telephone.data
            )
            db.session.add(add_customer)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New customer was successfully added')
        if address_form.validate_on_submit():
            add_address = Address(
                address_form.street.data,
                address_form.city.data,
                address_form.state.data,
                address_form.zip.data
            )
            db.session.add(add_address)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New Address was successfully added')
    return render_template('customers.html', customer_form=customer_form, address_form=address_form, error=error)
```

Template:

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h4>Add New Customer</h4>
<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action="/customers/">
  {{ customer_form.csrf_token }}
  {{ customer_form.name(placeholder="customer name") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if customer_form.name.errors %}
        {% for error in customer_form.name.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    {{ customer_form.telephone(placeholder="telephone number") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if customer_form.telephone.errors %}
        {% for error in customer_form.telephone.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    {{ customer_form.email(placeholder="email address") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if customer_form.email.errors %}
        {% for error in customer_form.email.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">Create</button>
  </form>


<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action="/customers/">
  {{ address_form.csrf_token }}
    <br>
    <h4>Add Address</h4>
    {{ address_form.priority }}
    {{ address_form.street(placeholder="street") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if address_form.street.errors %}
        {% for error in address_form.street.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    {{ address_form.city(placeholder="city") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if address_form.city.errors %}
        {% for error in address_form.city.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    {{ address_form.state(placeholder="state abbreviation") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if address_form.state.errors %}
        {% for error in address_form.state.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    {{ address_form.zip(placeholder="zip") }}
    <span class="error">
      {% if address_form.zip.errors %}
        {% for error in address_form.zip.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<br>
<h2>Search Customers</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Form Validation:

```
class AddCustomerForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Email()])
    telephone = StringField('Telephone', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=10, max=10)])


class AddAddressForm(Form):
    names = [(0, "Select Customer")]
    for k in customer_names():
        names.append((k.id, k.name))

    priority = SelectField(
            'Select Customer',  # this is the name of the field
            validators=[DataRequired()],
            choices=names)

    street = StringField('Street', validators=[DataRequired()])
    city = StringField('City', validators=[DataRequired()])
    state = StringField('State', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=2)])
    zip = StringField('Zip', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=5, max=5)])
```

Comment: you can have one form per page , if you have 2 or more forms in a same page it will submit the last one. but you can submit your forms with ajax to diffrent urls and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to add a name and value to your submit buttons and check the value in your handler:

```
<button ... name="action" value="add-customer">Create</button>

<button ... name="action" value="add-address">Add</button>
```

And in your handler, simply check the value of the `request.form["action"]` parameter:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.form.get("action") == "add-customer":
        # Add a customer
    elif request.form.get("action") == "add-address":
        # Add an address
```